# Javascript help-Menu

Tags: javascript, css, menu

Want to make it so when my menu items transition away, the search bar pops up.

```
let menuItemsQuerySelector = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
searchElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked search");
  menuItemsQuerySelector.forEach(function(menuItem) {
    console.log("Boom");
    menuItem.classList.toggle("hide-item");

  });
});
};
```

this is what i have so far to make the toggle animation work. my claases for the search bar are, search-from, i need to make it active somehow when the menu disappears. The css class is already set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "transitionend" event to execute code after the transition ends. 
You would have to add a boolean to check whether the transition was hidden-visible or visible-hidden

```
let hidden = false;
searchElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    hidden = true;
    //your other code
});

//Further down the line when showing your elements again
hidden = false;
```

However seeing that you have multiple elements that transition at the same time, you could either:
Hook the event only on one of them

```
menuItemsQuerySelector[0].on('transitionend', () => {
    if(hidden)
    //your code here
});
```

or Use a timed function

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if(hidden)
    //your code here
}, <delay in millisecods>);
```

Comment: so would the code i already have be under ``` menuItemsQuerySelector[0].on('transitionend', () => {
    if(hidden)
    //your code here?```